# Simple C++ code (what's wrong here?)

Tags: c++

Noob to C++.

I'm trying to get user input (Last Name, First Name Middle Name), change part of it (Middle Name to Middle Initial) and then rearrange it (First Middle Initial Last).

Where am I messing up in my code?

--Thanks for ANY help you can offer!

...

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

#include <string>
using std::string;

int main()
{

  string myString, last, first, middle;

  cout << "Enter your name: Last, First Middle";

  cin >> last >> first >> middle;

  char comma, space1, space2;

  comma = myString.find_first_of(',');
  space1 = myString.find_first_of(' ');
  space2 = myString.find_last_of(' ');

  last = myString.substr (0, comma); // user input last name
  first = myString.substr (space1+1, -1); // user input first name
  middle = myString.substr (space2+1, -1); // user input middle name

  middle.insert (0, space2+1); // inserts middle initial in front of middle name
  middle.erase (1, -1); // deletes full middle name, leaving only middle initial

  myString = first + ' ' + middle + ' ' + last; //  

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Well you search for things in `myString` but never set it to anything (it's an empty string).

You should read one whole line into `myString`.

```
std::getline(std::cin, myString);
```

Then you can look out for the `,` and spaces etc. The second problem is that you should use `size_t` as the type of comma, space1 and space2. These keep the positions of the spaces and commas in the string: If the comma or space isn't found in input, then the find functions return `string::npos`, which is the highest value in a `size_t`. But this would overflow a `char`. For reliably assigning the position, you should thus change the type of these three variables to `size_t`.

Then instead of using `-1` to say that you want to extract a substring until end just omit it: It has a default argument for that parameter which specifies `string::npos`. If you really want to pass it, maybe because it improves readability for you, use `string::npos` instead: It has the right type (`size_t`), and won't need a conversion of `int` (with value `-1`) to it.

Answer (score 12):

shouldn't this line :

```
cin >> last >> first >> middle;
```

be

```
cin >> myString;
```

?

Because after that you search for the comma and spaces in `myString` but this string contains nothing.

Comment: That won't work, because it will stop reading the line at the first space.

Comment: How'd this get so many upvotes... it won't work unless they enter their names without spaces...

Comment: @DeusAduro i didn't understand that either, That's why i upvoted litb's comment and anwser. JW should accept litb's answer so it goes up in the page and get highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  string myString, last, first, middle;

  cout << "Enter your name: Last, First Middle" << endl;

  getline(cin, myString);

  char comma, space1, space2;

  comma = myString.find_first_of(',');
  space1 = myString.find_first_of(' ');
  space2 = myString.find_last_of(' ');

  last = myString.substr (0, comma); // user input last name
  first = myString.substr (space1+1, space2 - space1); // user input first name
  middle = myString.substr (space2+1, -1); // user input middle name

  middle.erase(1, -1); // erases full middle name, only leaving the first character as initial

  cout << first << " " << middle << ". " << last << endl;//displays output

  return 0;
}
```

An easier way is to declare the whole namespace.

```
using namespace std;
```

Do try to use `getline()`if you want to include spaces in your input string.

```
getline(cin, myString);
```

Right here, you shouldn't use `-1` for your second parameter, else `first` will gladly be assigned of the rest of the string input.

```
first = myString.substr (space1+1, space2 - space1);
```

Also, the function `middle.erase` can't really accept a char as a parameter, a better way to go about this is to just write `-1` as you are trying to get rid of everything after the first char.

```
middle.erase(1, -1);
```

Finally, `myString = first + ' ' + middle + ' ' + last;` don't, just don't. I assume you are trying to display the results, `std::cout` would do just fine.

```
cout << first << " " << middle << ". " << last << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also instead of declearing so many `using` statements you could just include the namespace `std`
,so it should look like this.

```
//include headers..
using namespace std;
```